# Polymer 1.0: more-route selectedParams params not set

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am wondering if selectedParams is supported for Polymer 1.0.

I am following the doc of more-route
https://github.com/PolymerLabs/more-routing
in the README file.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/more-routing/more-routing.html">
<more-routing-config driver="hash"></more-routing-config>  

<more-route name="login" path="/">
</more-route>
<more-route name="inbox" path="/inbox">
    <more-route name="viewemail" path="/:threadId">
    </more-route>
</more-route>
<more-route-selector selectedParams="{{params}}" on-click="bodyClick">

    <iron-pages selected="{{route}}" class="fullbleed fit">
        <section route="login" >
        </section>
        <section route="viewemail" class="layout vertical fit">
            Test params : <span>{{params}}</span> End
            Test params : <span>{{params.threadId}}</span> End
            <span>{{route}}</span>
        </section>
    </iron-pages>
</more-route-selector>
```

The problem is that params is not set, so I cannot reference the threadId param in the path.

The routing it working which means for /inbox/testid is routed to section with route="viewemail", but params is not set.

Comment: After digging into the more-route code. It turns out that the property selectedParams is not set correctly in more-selector.html. I have raised issues in more-route repo but haven't got any response or comment so far.

Answer (score 0):

`selectedParams` should be written as `selected-params`. [From 1.0 docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#property-name-mapping):

> Attribute names with dashes are converted to camelCase property names by capitalizing the character following each dash, then removing the dashes. For example, the attribute first-name maps to firstName.

So your `more-route-selector` should be declared as follows:

```
<more-route-selector selected-params="{{params}}" on-click="bodyClick">
```

Comment: Yep. Think that's the convention. I cannot recall how is it in 0.5 time. I have tried this but not working. params is still undefined, it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <more-route name="viewemail" path="/:threadId">
```

above in "routes.html" binds name to the threadId you want a ref to ....

When you use those in template, get a context...

```
  <more-route context name="viewemail" params="{{params}}"></more-route>
```

... so you can make use of those properties within the Polymer class...

```
  ready: function() {
    if (typeof this.params.viewemail != 'undefined'){
      this._mvar = this.params.viewemail;
      this.$.get_divID = _mvar;
       if(MoreRouting.getRoute('viewemail').active){...}
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already pointed out in this [Github issue](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/more-routing/issues/72), the behavior is a bug of the Polymer 1.0 migration of `more-routing` (call it missing feature, as there is simply no instruction that would set the `selectedParams`).

As long as no fix exists, you have two options to circumvent the problem manually without modifying the project source code:

**1. *Workaround:* Listen on `on-more-route-change` on the `more-route-selector` element.**

The current routing params can be accessed as `event.detail.newRoute.params` from the event handler (caution: that object is not serializable due to non-enumerable JS getters). Manually hand over these params to your elements.

**2. *Good solution:* Use context-aware routes.**

`selectedParams` are not set on the `more-route-selector`, but well on routes. Include a context route to your pages and bind `{{params}}` on them.

Therefore, you may create a named route in your router file as:

```
<more-route path='/path/:param' name='path-route'/>
```

Reference this route by name from within your page element (or state the path directly):

```
<more-route context name='path-route' params='{{params}}'/>
```

Place the page element in `more-router-selector` as before. Parameters are bound to `{{params}}`.

The pattern is explained on the [project page](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/more-routing#routed-elements) and in use in the demo app.